# How to avoid expanding variables in bash here-string, like with here-document

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

shell scripting features can be disabled in a here-document by escaping characters in the ending marker defined on the first line.  For example:

```
$ cat <<'EOF'
→ $PATH
→ EOF
$PATH
```

Is there any way to do the same thing with a here-string so that one doesn't have to prepend each variable with a backslash?

`$ cat <<< $PATH` expands the variable before executing the bash command

Comment: `<<<$PATH` is bad form -- it should be `<<<"$PATH"` if expansion is desired, or `<<<'$PATH'` if it is not.

Comment: Note, for example, item `z` in the changelog between bash 4.4-alpha and 4.4-beta -- contrary to documentation, unquoted herestrings were subject to string-splitting, so values with spaces caused bugs. Using proper quoting prevents such bugs even on prior/unpatched releases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just backslash the dollar sign:

```
cat <<< \$PATH
```

or use single quotes

```
cat <<< '$PATH'
```

Comment: I should be clearer: I'm looking for a way to escape bash variables without having to escape each one

Comment: @WillB, in `<<<'hello $PATH $foo $bar bye'`, there *is* no escaping of "each one", single-quoting the entire string suffices.

Comment: @ZhaolinFeng: That was the point of the question, right?

Comment: @choroba You are totally correct. Sorry for misunderstanding the question. Can you edit the answer a bit, so I can withdraw my down-vote(it's locked unless the answer is edited).

Comment: @ZhaolinFeng: Is this enough?